# Как повесить на View одновременно OnClickListener и setOnTouchListener?

Tags: android

Как повесить на View одновременно OnClickListener и setOnTouchListener?

У меня :
   mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
   mLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener ()
и onClick не обрабатывается.

Comment: Попробуйте из onTouch false вернуть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это происходит, потому что сначала обрабатывается onTouch ,а в случае если он возвращает false, то срабатывает onClick. Вам нужно обрабатывать click в onTouch либо возвращать false всегда, когда обработка onTouch вам не нужна и тогда будет срабатывать onClick.